# Perform calculations on a list of values except for the first value in the list on Python

Tags: python

I have two data sets x and y and I want to perform some calculations on the x data set but without the first value as it is -inf. I would like to count the total number of values for x without the first value or to calculate the mean of values without the first value too.

I have tried running it on Python but I receive the error of RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

I also want to perform this formula without the first value of x:
m = l

```
m= len(x)-1

numer = 0
denom = 0
for i in range (m)
    
numer += (x[i] - mean_x) * (y[i] - mean_y)
denom += (x[i] - mean_x) ** 2
    
    

x = [-inf, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10,-11, -12, -13]
    
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please be aware this is not a code-writing service. We can help solving specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [ask] page for details how to best help us help you.

Comment: To clarify: Is your goal to disregard the first element, or to disregard any element that is ``-inf``/``inf``/``nan``/...?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi to disregard the first element of the x dataset from the numer + and denom + formulas

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Any suggestions?

Comment: You've added the error "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars" to the question – this is specific to the ``numpy`` library, which is *not* used in the code shown. If you are using ``numpy``, please state so since this changes the idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the number of values of x, or length, by just doing `len(x)-1`. Also, you declared both lists wrong. There should be a `[` right before the first number and a `]` right after the last number.

You can use the `statistics` library in pyton to find the mean. To exclude the first value of the list, you can write `x[1:]`.

Combine them:

```
import statistics
statistics.mean(x[1:])
```

Comment: Thanks @NumberC. Just to clarify, is this what you mean: numer += (x[1:] - mean(x[1:])) * (y[i] - mean_y) and denom += (x[1:] - mean(x[1:])) ** 2 ?

Comment: This should still work. If you didn't specify what `i` was, you might get an error though.

Comment: Note that there is no problem declaring a "list" without opening ``[`` and closing ``]``. ``x = 1, 2, 3, 4`` creates a tuple ``x``.